# ¿Como solucionar el nivel de api 30 a 31 en mi app de ionic con capacitor?

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic, ionic-framework, capacitor

Me sale el siguiente erro a la hora de subir mi app a play store:

> Actualmente, el nivel de la API de destino de tu aplicación es el 30, pero debe ser al menos 31 para garantizar que se compile con las API más recientes, que ofrecen una seguridad y un rendimiento óptimos. Cambia el nivel de la API de destino de tu aplicación al nivel 31 como mínimo

Ya he subido el nivel de api a 31 modificandolo en el Project structure de android studio, cambie los valores en el graddle, pero me tira un error con la version de android 12, no se como solucionarlo, agradeceria me ayudaran, así tengo la imagen actualmente, pero firmo la app y me sigue saliendo igual

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Debido a que capacitor esta en su versión 4 y android ya va para la version 13, hay que implemetar unos cambios en el variables gradle, ademas cambiar la version del Graddle

Como nos dice en la documentacion: https://capacitorjs.com/docs/updating/4-0

Comment: puedes añadir los detalles más relevantes de lo que dice el enlace en tu respuesta? la idea es que no muera la respuesta si el enlace cambia y se rompe

Answer (score 0):

Intenta editar el archivo `variable.gradle` con:
`minSdkVersion = 22 compileSdkVersion = 32 targetSdkVersion = 32`

También el en `AndroidManifest` en la etiqueta `<activity>` agregar:
`android:exported="true"`

Asegúrate que estes usando Java 11:
`Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle`
Y en Gradle JDK selecciona 11.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/370123)

Answer (score 0):

Actualiza a capacitor 4.

```
npm install @capacitor/cli@latest
npx cap migrate
```

Respondes a las preguntas que te haga (son 3) y en pocos segundos (o algún minuto si seleccionas si a instalar paquetes) tendrás tu app actualizada y usando capacitor 4 y los últimos plugins compatibles con SDK 32.